# Cancel update-database command - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use the command `update-database` on npm. It's shows fail to update-database because the database is read-only on npm console. So I know this DB can't be updated but when I check my website I realize it causes this error on my server IIS. I tried to reset IIS server & SQL Server but It does work. And I can't change this DB because this out site my permission. So I want to know there is any way I could cancel `update-database` command.

[image]

Comment: You say yourself "you can't update", and a try to update causes an error. 
This is a statement not a question. If you cannot, you cannot. You have no permission, that's it.

Comment: But after I use command `update-databse` it causes an error on my IIS server. Now I know that this database can't be updated. So I want to cancel `update-database` command to fix this bug. It's caused that bug on every IIS server that use this database.

Comment: Don't raise this command. So you don't need to cancel it. Why do you use this command, if you know it's not working ?
If EF wants to update it automaticly, it means you have made changes to your EF-Code, that have to be applied to the database. But it cannot be applied, so don't change any of your EF classes.Never ever.

Comment: I fix this bug by created another database with a read and write. I thought the problem is with EF calling the update command but it's not. The problem is in my ASP.NET run database SetInitializer every time the web start. So it's called `update-databse` because my DB is different from my EF model.